# Convert HSV to RGB in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rgb, hsv

I have [H,S,V] colour values.
How can I convert them to [R,G,B] in MATLAB?

I've tried with the algorithm but I'm having some problems. Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: why you don't use matlab function for your transform?

Comment: I mean, there is literally a function called `hsv2rgb`

Comment: What algorithm? What problems? Please be more specific.

Comment: You can have a look at the source code of `hsv2rgb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the in-built [`hsv2rgb`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv2rgb.html) function...

```
% Some colour in HSV, [Hue (0-360), Saturation (0-1), Value (0-1)]
myHSV = [217, 0.4, 0.72];
% hsv2rgb takes Hue value in range 0-1, so...
myHSV(1) = myHSV(1) / 360;
% Convert to RGB with values in range (0-1)
myRGBpct = hsv2rgb(myHSV);
% Convert to RGB with values in range (0-255)
myRGB255 = myRGBpct * 255;
```

Putting all of this together, we can simply do

```
myHSV = [217, 0.4, 0.72];
myRGB255 = hsv2rgb(myHSV ./ [360, 1, 1]) * 255; 
>> myRGB255 = [110.16, 138.31, 183.60]
```

Testing this using [Google's color picker](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=color+picker), we can see this is the correct solution. If you wanted to do any other RGB manipulation within MATLAB then leave the values in the range (0-1), since that is what MATLAB always uses.

[image: blue]

If you have many HSV values, store them in an `mx3` matrix, with columns H,S and V. Then similarly to the above you can do:

```
myHSV = [217, 0.4, 0.72;
         250, 0.5, 0.2; 
         % ... more rows
        ];
myHSV(:,1) = myHSV(:,1) / 360;
myRGB255 = hsv2rgb(myHSV) * 255;
```